# How to solve this system with equation and inequality?

Tags: exponential-function, quadratics

$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
2^{x+2}=\frac{49}{4}x^2+4, \\
2^{x+2}-4\le x^2(14-2^{x+2})*2^x
\end{aligned}
\right.$

Task is simple - solve this system.

Using some tricks I solved inequality 
$x \in (-\frac{2\sqrt3}{7}; \frac{2\sqrt3}{7})$.

But how to solve equation?

Comment: Could you please give us the full context in which this problem is posed? Maybe you are required to find only the integer roots, or only their number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as suspected, your edit brings a new piece of information (the inequation) that allows to easily solve that system using only high-school mathematics (the role of the inequality being to rule out the "ugly" non-zero solutions) - with the exception of a single step in the proof that seems to require very high-level mathematics.

For simplicity, let $t = 2^x$. The equation implies that $x^2 = \dfrac {16} {49} (t-1)$. Plugging this into the inequality and performing all the necessary simplifications brings it to

$$(t-1)(49 - 56t + 16t^2) \le 0 .$$

Inside the second pair of brackets one recognizes $(7 - 4t)^2$, so there are only two possibilities:

- either $t-1 \ge 0$ and $(7 - 4t)^2 \le 0$,
- or $t-1 \le 0$ and $(7 - 4t)^2 \ge 0$.

Since $(7 - 4t)^2 \ge 0$, the first possibility implies that $(7 - 4t)^2 = 0$, so that $t = \dfrac 7 4$, which also satisfies $t - 1 \ge 0$. Returning to $x$, this has the consequence that $2^x = \dfrac 7 4$ and $x^2 = \dfrac {12} {49}$, or equally well $x = \log_2 7 - 2$ and $x = \pm \dfrac {2 \sqrt 3} 7$. Since $x = \log_2 7 - 2 \ge \log_2 4 - 2 = 0$, it follows that $x$ cannot take that negative value. Can it take the positive one? Assuming it could, this would mean that $\log_2 7 = 2 + \dfrac {2 \sqrt 3} 7$, which after exponentiation would be equivalent to $\dfrac 7 4 = 4^ {\dfrac {\sqrt 3} 7}$. This, in turn, implies that $4^ {\dfrac {\sqrt 3} 7} \in \Bbb Q$, which after raising to the $7$th power implies that $4^ \sqrt 3 \in \Bbb Q$. This is not true, but I do not know how to prove this at a high-school level. Maybe you are supposed to use a scientific calculator to solve your problem? Anyway, that $4^ \sqrt 3$ is irrational is a consequence of [the Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), or of [the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), both of them, though, being vastly out of the reach of high-school pupils. In any case, the conclusion so far is that $t = \dfrac 7 4$ does not lead to solutions of the given system.

The second possibility reduces to $t-1 \le 0$, because the square is always $\ge 0$, but since $x^2 = \dfrac {16} {49} (t-1)$, this would imply that $x^2 = 0$ ($0$ being the only number both $\ge 0$ and $\le 0$), which has the only solution $x=0$.

---

The analysis could have been performed equally well by replacing $t$ with $\dfrac {49} {16} x^2 + 1$ and performing all the compuations with $x$, instead of with $t$, but the reasoning would have reached the same difficult point about $\log_2 7$ that has been reached above.

Answer (score 0):

with a numerical method we find $$x=0$$ or $$0.246850313904907537017$$ or $$7.3972850014872596165$$ now you can findout which solutions lies in your interval

Comment: What about the $x=0$??

Comment: $x=0$ is also a solution i have forgotten to type this

Comment: I'm more interested in detailed solution than roots.

Comment: use the Newton-Raphson method

Comment: I doubt that this method is taught in high school

Comment: there is also the Regula falsi mthod

Comment: You write: "With ***a*** numerical method we find...."  Please, at the very least, and IN YOUR Answer (as opposed to in a comment below your answer), specify specifically **the** particular numerical method which you used to obtain the result. And if you're going to appeal to a specific numerical method to justify your answer, you need to show how to apply the particular method *in this case."

Comment: This equation is not solved by elementary methods, you will HAVE to resort to a numerical method to get an approximation to a solution. Of course, there are many ways to do this. Consider halving your interval and testing endpoints until you get something close.

Comment: for the computations see here http://keisan.casio.com/has10/SpecExec.cgi?id=system/2006/1222999093

Comment: Then why is this example written in my textbook algebra?)

Answer (score 0):

My idea is not completed way to find all roots but may be help the O.P to find some roots
$$2^x=\frac{49}{16}x^2+1$$
$$x\log 2=\log(\frac{49}{16}x^2+1)$$
$$x=\frac{\log(\frac{49}{16}x^2+1)}{\log 2}$$ 
by using the iteration method, we can write the last equation as follow
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{\log(\frac{49}{16}x_n^2+1)}{\log 2}$$ 
by using this equation we can get two roots only 
$$x_0=0$$
$$x_1=7.3972850014872596165$$

Comment: For some mysterious reason you are mising a root - see Dr. Graubner's answer. Notice also that the root $7.397\ldots$ does not lie within the given bounds.

Comment: @AlexM. I accept with you but I wanted to show the way which maybe sometime gives all roots.